# Testing component function in React with Enzyme and Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing a component following the Container/Presentational pattern. What I need in order to have my coverage at 100% is to test the handleChange() function in which I have a setState(). The thing is that I'm just testing the Container component and the function is called in Presentational one.

**Container Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DataStructureFormView from './DataStructureFormView'

export default class DataStructureForm extends Component {
    state = {}

    handleChange = name => event => {
        this.setState({
            [name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DataStructureFormView
               handleChange={this.handleChange}
               form={this.state}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see, the DataStructureForm is the Container component and DataStructureFormView is the Presentational one.

**Test file:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'

describe('DataStructureForm', () => {
    it('should call the handleChange() function and change the state', () => {
        const component = mount(<DataStructureForm />)

        const handleChange = jest.spyOn(component.instance(), 'handleChange')

        component.instance().handleChange()

        expect(handleChange).toBeCalled()
     }
}
```

This is one of the multiple approaches that I have done, but it is not testing the setState() inside the handleChange() method.

What else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is to check if state changed accordingly:

```
const component = shallow(<DataStructureForm />)
const value = 'someValue';
component.instance().handleChange('someName')({target: { value }});
expect(component.state('someName')).toEqual(value)
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex, that is the solution. The problem was I didn't how to call the handleChange() function.